# Create manual counter for references to not yet written objects

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels

I am  typesetting a document for somebody else who is writing it by hand and I do not have the full text yet. However the text I already typeset contains references to Sections and equations in the chapters to come.
Therefore I already created some labels, I will use as soon as I get to the new part. Until then latex puts **??** as a place holder.

Now I have the following problem:
For reviewing the text I hand it back and people for some reason get irritated with the placeholders. Of course I can just put the numbers the references will probably have in the future until I can add the proper references but that seems inconvenient.

Would there be a way of numbering the labels which are not yet in use manually but in a common location - for instance in the preamble - so I don't have to chase them down one by one in my document and replace them by the numbers they'll probably have anyways in the future?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you already know the structure of the future chapters and sections you could just insert these as empty sections with corresponding labels. This way you also get meaningful numbers.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to replace the `??` by some text then to invent some numbers?

Comment: You could use the existing counters (equaton, figure, table, section) and add a "to be completed" secton at the end consisting of "description \refstepcounter{equation}\label{...}" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments on the question give good advice, i.e., either create an outline with sections that don't have content yet, or replace the ?? by "nr. tbd" or something. However, to implement the suggested approach:

Referencing in LaTeX works internally by setting the value of the macro `\@currentlabel`. This macro is normally set by commands like `\section` or `\begin{equation}`. A `\label` command stores the value of `\@currentlabel` at that point to the `.aux` file, which is used to resolve `\ref` commands.

You can also set `\@currentlabel` yourself, with an arbitrary value, and issue a `\label` command directly after to store that label with the associated value to the `.aux` file. As an example a small macro `\placeholder` with two arguments that does this. Because `\@currentlabel` contains an `@` symbol you need to surround the macro definition by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

If you use `hyperref` then you need a `\phantomsection` before the label so hyperref has something to refer to (which is the call of `\placeholder` in this case.

Note that I added a prefix `ph` to the value to highlight that this is a placeholder.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\placeholder}[2]{%
\def\@currentlabel{ph#2}%
%\phantomsection% needed if hyperref is loaded
\label{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\placeholder{sec:conclusion}{3.1}
\placeholder{sec:discussion}{3.2}
\placeholder{sec:appendix}{A}
\section{Introduction}
We don't know what will happen yet. Once we do, we will make sure to describe it in sections \ref{sec:conclusion}, \ref{sec:discussion} and Appendix \ref{sec:appendix}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. This was exactely what I was looking for.